# Improving precision while maintaining recall with YOLO models

Tags: computer-vision, yolo

We are trying to build an object detection application for handheld objects (wallet, knife, phone etc) which requires high precision and recall.

Tried with YoloV4 and V7 models with around 20K images per class. Achieved testing MAP around 80% , precision 90 and recall around 75 However, We are facing issues with false detections and missing detection when objects are in certain angle during field test. What are the options to improve the model further ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to collect more images and you need more epochs to detect more accurately.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).